# How to show to show that $S^{\bot}$ is a linear subspace of $V$ and $(U^{\bot})^{\bot}=U$?

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $V$ be an Euclidean vector space with scalar product $(.|.)$. If $S ⊂ V$ is any subset of $V$ , define the orthogonal complement of $S$ by
$$S^{\bot}=\left\{v\in V| \left(s|v\right)=0\forall s\in S\right\}$$

I need to show that $S^{\bot}$ is a linear subspace of $V$ and also that $(U^{\bot})^{\bot}=U$, if $U$ is a linear subspace of $V$ and $V$ is finite-dimensional.

What if show first that $U ⊂ (U^{\bot})^{\bot}$, then use the followingfact:If $\dim V =n$, $\dim U=m$, then $\dim U^{\bot} =n−m$? But I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints:

(1) Check that
$$v,w\in S^\bot\implies \lambda v+\mu w\in S^\bot$$
i.e. if $s\in S$,
$$(s|v\lambda v+\mu w)=\cdots $$
(2) Prove that $U$ and $(U^{\bot})^{\bot}$ have the same dimension.